# Return owner fields from silverstripe $many_many relationship

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a many_many relationship between TestimonialBlocks <--> Testimonials, defined as:

```
class TestimonialBlockSlice extends ContentSlice
{
    private static $db = array (
        'IconColour' => 'Enum("White,Blue,Green,Orange","Green")'
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'Testimonials' => 'Testimonial'
    );

    private static $many_many_extraFields = array(
        'Testimonials' => array('SortOrder' => 'Int')
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
            ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldDeleteAction')
            ->addComponents(new GridFieldDeleteAction('unlinkrelation'));
        $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
            'Text'=> 'Text',
            'Author'=> 'Author'
        ));

        $testimonialsField = new GridField(
            'Testimonials',
            'Testimonial',
            $this->Testimonials(),
            $config
        );

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $testimonialsField);
        return $fields;
    }
}


class Testimonial extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Text' => 'Text',
        'Author' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'TestimonialBlocks' => 'TestimonialBlockSlice'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Text' => 'Text',
        'Author' => 'Author'
    );
}
```

Everything works fine, but in the template I cannot get the $IconColour of the containing TestimonialBlockSlice...I've tried everything I can think of. I am doing something like this:

```
<% loop Testimonials.Limit(2) %>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="icon-quote"><img src="/themes/images/icon-quote-{ ##getIconColourHere## }.png"></div>
        <div class="testimonial-text">$Text</div>
        <div class="testimonial-author">$Author</div>
    </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

TestimonialBlockSlice extends heyday/silverstripe-slices, where ContentSlice is a DataObject.
Any ideas on how to reference the IconColour of this particular TestimonialBlockSlice?  help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

When you enter a loop, you enter [the scope/context](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#scope) of the item you're looping. In this case you're within the context of a `Testimonial`.

`IconColour` belongs to the `TestimonialBlockSlice` class (parent), so you can move ["up" a scope level](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#up) to access it:

```
<% loop Testimonials.Limit(2) %>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="icon-quote"><img src="/themes/images/icon-quote-{$Up.IconColour}.png"></div>
        <div class="testimonial-text">$Text</div>
        <div class="testimonial-author">$Author</div>
    </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Thanks Robbie, thats one of the first things I tried :)  But, doesn't work in this case...

Comment: Just noticed I'd used IconColor - edited to show IconColour